# Windows phone can't save CookieContainer

Tags: windows-phone-8

I apologize for my english :)
I catch cookies from server. And try to save it in order to use cookeis later.

```
 var Settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
 CookieContainer _Cookie = new CookieContainer()
_Cookie.Add(new Uri("http://www.portal.fa.ru/Job/SearchResultDiv"), response.Cookies);
            Settings.Clear();

            Settings["UserID"] = userID;
            Settings["Cookie"] = _Cookie;

            Settings.Save();
```

Ok it working. But after restart app cookie has losted. (Object has remain but cookies count = 0). I don't know.
So i try to convert from CookieContainer to array byte than save and load it when i need it.

```
public static byte[] ToByte(CookieContainer data)
    {
        byte[] CookieByte;
        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(CookieContainer));
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, data);
            CookieByte = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
        return CookieByte;
    }


    public static CookieContainer FromByte(byte[] data)
    {
        CookieContainer Cookie;
        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(CookieContainer));
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
            Cookie =  (CookieContainer)serializer.ReadObject(memoryStream);
        }
        return Cookie;
    }
```

But this code did not work again. When i convert to byte and back i losing cookies (count = 0). 
So what can i do?
PS write pls your code when you deal with authorization and cookies. Thx

Comment: So, you mean the proper cookies remains but the cookies number isn't?

Comment: No no no cookie not save. I say "count = 0" in order to show fact that cookie remains